# Authentication failing on Kestrel but not on IIS Express

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am new to .net core and attempting a web app with a login page that uses the provided authentication features in asp .net-core.

When I created the web app and built it up, I used IISExpress to run it and the authentication features worked correctly and allowed me to login and use various operations on the web app.

I am now attempting to change from IIExpress to Kestrel and running into some difficulty with authenticating users on logon.

```
info: RestartTool.Controllers.AccountController[0]
  User logged in.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToActionResult[1]
  Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to /.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
  Executed action RestartTool.Controllers.AccountController.Login (RestartTool) in 3330.8233ms
```

So, when using Kestrel, the user is "logged in" correctly as the user/password entered is correct. And therefore it is meant to redirect to Index, or /.

```
  Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:59211/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
  Authorization failed for user: (null).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
  Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
  Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
```

However, the above error messages arise in the console, and the page eventually redirects back to the login page without the user logged in.

In my startup Configure method, I have added the following line that a lot of answers seem to show the fix as but it does not make a difference (as it was already there)

```
            app.UseAuthentication();
```

If it's useful, in my ConfigureServices Method I am setup as follows: (with a little bit more to specify password settings)

```
  services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
services.AddMvc();
```

I am curious to what the problem could be since it works correctly on IIExpress but not on Kestrel. If you need me to provide any more code please let me know. Any help in the matter would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT** - Cookie configuration in `ConfigureServices`:

```
/* services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                // Cookie settings
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(150);
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login"; // If the LoginPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Login
                options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout"; // If the LogoutPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Logout
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied"; // If the AccessDeniedPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/AccessDenied
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });*/
```

I have essentially followed this tutorial for creating this, and I don't believe there are many changes from this: [Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x)

Comment: May you add the line of code that you set the user to Authorized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by logging out on the II Express page and then it was able to log me in and authenticate successfully running on Kestrel..